# Trying to drop a column on MySQL when connecting to Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am using a machine learning decision tree on Python to connect to a database that is on MySQL and am getting an error when the values in the database are used in the code. The code on python receives inputs that will match UPC values stored in MySQL and output the rows that match to be used in python. I am getting an error when comparing values in one of the decision tree functions and think it is the UPC value causing this error as it is a long number. Is there a way to have the other elements of the row match without bringing the UPC value with it? The error message I am receiving may not be due to this but I would also like to not have the UPC column be used when the values are imported to the decision tree.

```
CARMLScursor = mydb.cursor()

print("Enter upc codes via scanner (type f to finish list): ")

try:
    input_upc = []

    while True:
        input_upc.append(int(input()))

except:
    print("Listed UPC input:", input_upc)

CARMLScursor.execute("use supermarket")

sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO user_input (Barcode) VALUES(%s)"

records = zip(input_upc)

CARMLScursor.executemany(sqlFormula, records)

mydb.commit()

SQL connection:
copy = "SELECT t1.* FROM items t1, user_input t2 WHERE (t1.UPC=t2.Barcode) " \
       "GROUP BY t1.UPC, t1.Shelf, t1.Isle, t1.ItemName ORDER BY Isle ASC"

CARMLScursor.execute(copy)

result = [CARMLScursor.fetchall()]

for training_data in result:

    print(training_data)
```

Part receiving error:

```
class Question:

    def __init__(self, column, value):
        self.column = column
        self.value = value

    def match(self, example):
        # Compare the feature value in an example to the
        # feature value in this question.
        val = example[self.column + 2]
        if is_numeric(val):
            return val >= self.value
        else:
            return val == self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        # This is just a helper method to print
        # the question in a readable format.
        condition = "=="
        if is_numeric(self.value):
            condition = ">="
        return "Is %s %s %s?" % (
            header[self.column], condition, str(self.value))

q = Question(0, 'Cereal')
print(q)

example = training_data[0]
print(q.match(example))


def partition(rows, question):

    true_rows, false_rows = [], []
    for row in rows:
        if question.match(row):
            true_rows.append(row)
        else:
            false_rows.append(row)
    return true_rows, false_rows
```

line 116, in match return val >= self.value
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

This shows the table that acts as an inventory where the scanned UPC matches the stored ones. There is another table called user_input where the UPC values scanned are stored that have the same attributes as the items table.

```
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|        UPC        |     Shelf    |    Isle    |    ItemName   |                  
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789851   |       C      |     1      |     Eggs      |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789789   |       A      |     1      |     Milk      |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789765   |       D      |     2      |     Coffee    |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789582   |       A      |     5      | Apple Juice   |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                 
|    123456789542   |       S      |     2      |     Cereal    |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|
```

Comment: Please show the lines of how class object, *Question*, is initialized and its `match` method called.

Comment: Also, why are you running `GROUP BY` without any aggregation and especialy with `SELECT *`? Unfortunately, MySQL (pre 8.0+) allows this invalid SQL statement with default settings. Also, be sure to learn about explicit `JOIN`s (standard in SQL since 1992) as right now you are using the outmoded implicit join.

Comment: I have added the code where the match function is used. We were under the impression that using GROUP BY it would import information from the second table to the first table if two columns (the UPC values) matched. We will look into the explicit JOINs now. Thanks.